# how can i know the footprint of my .so library?

Tags: c, linux, memory, shared-libraries, static-libraries

In embedded we often listen word like low footprint library.

so how can i know the footprint of my library.so or library.a file..?
how can i calculate that

is it same as the memory size of that library?

Comment: Please define "footprint".  Do you mean the memory consumed by loading an executable that includes that library?  Do you mean the maximum live heap for any given library routine?  Something else?

Comment: i want to know memory consumed by loading an executable that includes that library..            & i think maximum live heap for any given library routine is seen by pmap -(process id of that application using that library) in linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real why to find out the memory footprint is by running the executable that uses the library and see how it uses it. An executable typically uses only a subset of a library. For example a library might have a list that holds objects that are dynamically created by the library when a client pushes another item to the list. The more items that are pushed to the list, the more memory consumed by the library.

You can see how much memory a process consumes (heap and otherwise) by looking in procfs: **cat /proc//mem**.

"**ps aux**" will also give you the virtual memory size (VSZ).

Comment: Virtual size is rather meaningless. You should look at `/proc/$pid/smaps` and check the mappings of the library and the anonymous mapping just after it. This will be the library's code, data, and bss. For each, pay special attention to how much is actually resident, and perhaps more importantly, how much is **dirty**. This is the actual memory usage that's not just cached copies of constant data on disk (which can be discarded and reloaded if memory gets tight).